# angularJS emptying input field on filter

Tags: javascript, angularjs, input

Today I faced a situation with angularJS.

Hi have a recipe website, and to list the ingredients and theyr respective dosage I'm using angular's ng-repeat (here goes the snippet).

```
<div ng-repeat="food in foodList | filter:query">
    <label>
        {{food.name}}
    </label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control food-list-input" data-id="{{food.ingredientId}}" placeholder="Weight in grams.">
</div>
```

The thing is that when I apply the filter, all inputs I previously inserted some value, if they are hidden because of the filter, they return to empty.

Is there anyway around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you probably want to bind the input to something using `ng-model`, for example:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="food.dosage" class="form-control food-list-input" data-id="{{food.ingredientId}}" placeholder="Weight in grams.">
```

That will implement two-way binding from your model to the `input` tag, so that when `ng-repeat` re-runs, the previously entered values will be re-bound from the model.

Comment: It worked! Had a bad time giving the ng-model a name ( since the input fields were dynamicaly loaded ) but it's fine now. 

Thanks!